# Python tabula-py cannot import name wrapper

Tags: python-3.x, tabula, tabula-py

Here is my code:

```
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf('singapore.pdf')
```

But it gives following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper'

I tried it on ubuntu and it works fine there but on Windows I am unable to use this code, as it always gives the above error. I installed tabula by using this command:

> pip3 install tabula-py

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved it, you need to add java path to environment variables. More details can be found here:

https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#get-tabula-py-working-windows-10